# 2nd order linear ODE

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have to solve the following ODE:

$$\frac{a}{\lambda}\sqrt{a^{2}-1}\frac{df}{da}-2\mu^{2}\frac{f(a)^{2}}{a^{2}}+\frac{a^{4}}{2\lambda^{2}}=0$$

with respect to $f(a)$, where $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are constants. I first tried changing time coordinate by the transformation: $da/dt=a\sqrt{a^{2}-1}/\lambda$ and linearize by setting $f(a)=\kappa a^{2}\dot{\nu}/\nu$ where dot corresponds to t differentiation. What I obtain is:

$$\ddot{f}+2\tan(t)\dot{f}-\mu^{2}\frac{f}{\cos(t)^{2}}=0 $$

where I substituted $a=1/\cos(t/\lambda)$ and rescaled by $t/\lambda=\tau$ to get rid of the $\lambda$ dependence.

I have to say that Mathematica can solve this and the initial, however it looks quite nasty so I was wondering if anyone had any ideas how to reduce it to a simpler form.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried/attempted to do to reduce this into a simpler form?

Comment: Yes this is actually the simplest I have been able to make it too....

Comment: Ah, okay, then you should re-edit your question to include the original form of the ODE, as there could exist other tricks from that original that could make it easier to simplify

Comment: ok I just did what you suggested. Thank you!

Comment: If there is a region of $a$ such that $1 \ll a \ll (\lambda \mu)^{1/3}$, then in this region I think we can conclude that $$ f(a) \approx \frac{a^6}{4\lambda^2\mu^2}.$$
This comes from (a) taking $a\gg 1$, (b) dropping the derivative term to solve an algebraic equation, before (c) checking with the solution of this algebraic equation under what conditions dropping the derivative term was valid -- handwavy asymptotics

Comment: I dont think that this is right. The equation can be easily solved through mathematica in the region a>>1 and gives a relatively simple answer for f(a) which scales as $a^{3}$